# Forma mas apropiada para ejecutar varios HILOS (task, threads) de forma simultanea

Tags: c#, windows-forms

Estoy preparando un DASHBOARD donde debo hacer varias consultas a la base de datos para traer diferentes listas. En concreto debo traer 5 listas diferentes, pero me gustaría ir presentando valores en el formulario de manera dinámica sin esperar que se haya llenado la ultima lista. Creo que lo mas apropiado seria la utilización de HILOS para tan pronto reciba la primera lista poder desplegar dichos datos. Cual es la mejor manera para ejecutar 5 hilos de forma simultanea y asegurarme que todos hagan su parte de forma correcta. Ahora mismo algunas veces no todos los hilos se ejecutan y algunos controles del formulario no reciben su valor. Nota, una lista en especifico se puede tomar hasta 10 segundos en ser devuelta.

Pongo parte de código para ilustrar.

```
        Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        {
            this.hilo_uno();
            this.parte_uno();
        };

        Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        {
            this.hilo_dos();
            this.parte_dos();
        };

    private void hilo_uno()
    {
        // aqui hago una consulta a base datos y devuelvo una lista
    }

    private void hilo_dos()
    {
        // aqui hago una consulta a base datos y devuelvo una lista
    }

    private void parte_uno()
    {

        this.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
        {
           // aqui recibo la lista llenada en hilo uno y paso los valores a los objetos del formulario. Lo mimso para hilo_dos y el mentodo parte_dos.
        });
    }
```

Comment: Tenes los nombres equivocados, un Hilo es un Thread, vos trabajas con Task que no podes manejar la forma ciertas propiedades que el Thread si. Deberias poner el codigo del metodo que te trae la info de la base de datos, para ver todo.

Comment: Gracias Ramiro, me hiciste ver mi fallo. He cambiado de Task a Thread y he resuelto mi problema. No se si tenemos forma de darte el voto positivo, pero si das esa respuesta creo que podria hacerlo.